# How to pass the content of a TeX variable to Lua without luastring and luacode?

Tags: luatex, strings

I try to pass the content of a Tex variable to lua, but I don't use luacode. Is there a way to avoid it ?

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{pgfkeys}
%\pgfkeys{
%   JobName/.code={\directlua{ JobName = \jobname }},
%   JobName,
%}

\begin{document}

\directlua{ JobName = \jobname }
\directlua{ tex.print ("The job name is :" .. JobName) }

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a Lua string assignment so

```
JobName = "\jobname"
```

or

```
\directlua{ JobName = "\luaescapestring{\jobname}" }
```

If you need exotic filenames